# How to update a reagent atom with a vector of maps in Clojure

Tags: clojure, swap, reagent

Let's say I have a reagent atom with a vector of maps like this:

```
(def my-atom (reagent/atom [{:id 1 :name "first name"}
                            {:id 2 :name "second name"}]))
```

How can I update the value of a key at a certain vector index to be this:

```
[{:id 1 :name "first name"}
 {:id 2 :name "UPDATED second name"}]
```

I'm looking for a function  like `(update-my-atom 1 :name "UPDATED second name")`:

```
(defn update-my-atom
  [vector-index key new-value]
  (swap! ??? - ???)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`assoc-in`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/assoc-in/) works with any nesting of associative structures, including maps inside vectors*. As such, I'd recommend a `swap!` with `assoc-in`

```
  (swap! my-atom assoc-in [vector-index key] new-value)
```

*: As does `update-in`, if you want to use a function of the old value instead of "this is the new value".